# Using _.groupBy and it works, but I want to ROLLUP all salaries using _.reduce with Underscore

Tags: json, underscore.js

I'm using Underscore to _.groupBy a JSON object by EMPLOYER. There are MANY JOB TITLES under that EMPLOYER with SALARIES per JOB TITLE.

Hence, I want to roll-up the TOTAL of all salaries.

Here's a short example of what I have:

```
ctrlMain.regroupedReport2 = _.groupBy(ctrlMain.report2, function (obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj.empname);
});
```

The value of the original data is HERE:

Each Company looks like this... Now, there's more data in the JSON but for clarity, I've shown only the VALUES I need.

TTL SALARIES would appear RIGHT JUSTIFIED on the same row as EMPLOYER.

Yes, this is a custom Datatables.net table.

[image]

This is what UNDERSCORE CREATES....

```
"AVOCENT HUNTSVILLE CORP": [{
    pwsalary: "$83,179.00"
    salary: "$83,179.00"
},{
    pwsalary: "$111,446.00"
    salary: "$129,064.00"
},{
    pwsalary: "$111,446.00"
    salary: "$129,064.00"
},{
    pwsalary: "$122,283.00"
    salary: "$134,482.50"
}]
```

THE PROBLEM:

With the companies as the UPPER OBJECT; how to I access the INNER ARRAY for each company, by the "NAME OF COMPANY" or by INDEX; [0],[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYsyT.png),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQFNY.png),... [n]

**UPDATE**

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.
Each EMPLOYER has 1 - 'n' number of JOBs with salaries.
I want to ROLL UP the SUM into the salaryRollup'n'  under EACH GROUP!

[image: This is an example of what I'm attempting to accomplish. Rollup CHILD SALARIES to PARENT 'GROUP' row]

HTH

UPDATE:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var a = {
  "ACME": [{
    "salary": "100000.00"
  }, {
    "salary": "52500.00"
  }],
  "JOHNSON CONTROLS": [{
    "salary": "42525.00"
  }, {
    "salary": "72500.00"
  }, {
    "salary": "62500.00"
  }, {
    "salary": "82500.00"
  }]
};
var ttl = [];
var col1_sum = _.reduce(a,
  function(memo, obj) {
    console.log("MEMO: ", obj)
    for (var e = 0; e < obj.length; e++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        ttl[i] = memo + parseFloat(obj[i].salary);
      }
        return ttl[e];      
    }
  }, 0);
console.log("TOTALS: ", ttl);
$("#sum").html(col1_sum)
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sum"></div>
```

The answer I'm getting is:

```
142525
```

What I need is the TOTAL OF ALL ACME SALARIES and the TOTAL OF ALL of JOHNSON CONTROLS SALARIES.

That's it.  The FINAL TOTAL will appear in the graphic for the COMPANY on the far right.

Comment: Peter, if that is live data it may be prudent to anonymize it. Or get me a job at that company :)

Comment: LOL! Gruff, can't get you a job there but wait until you see what I'm building!  So, elaborate on anonymize it, please.